# tangent bundle of $\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let V be a two dimensional vector space over k. Consider the set of  isomorphism classes of all rank 1 $k[x]/x^2$-submodules of $V\otimes k[x]/x^2$. Does this set has a variety structure? Is it tangent bundle of $\mathbb{P}^1$?

Comment: What does rank mean for you for a ring with nilpotents?

Comment: rank of a module over a commutative ring.....is there a problem?

Comment: rank 1 free submodules should be  generated by an element like $v\otimes (a+bx)$ where $v\in V$ and $a+bx\in k[x]/x^2$ and $a\neq 0$.                        By the way i meant to say rank 1 locally free submodules of V⊗k[x]/x2 in the main question .

Comment: Yes there is a problem. What is the rank of $k[x]/x$ over $k[x]/x^2$?

Comment: Rank is 0..because no element in k is linearly independent...multiplication by x is 0...this is why I said $a\neq 0$

Comment: It is torsion free but not flat

Comment: Oh boy, I am really confused. $a+bx$ with $a\neq 0$ is a unit, so the submodule generated by $v\otimes(a+bx)$ is the same as the one generated by $v\otimes 1$ and it is free, but you say not flat!

Comment: I was talking about k [x]/x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be classical to consider varieties as sets, but I think it is having counterproductive effects on communication in this case.  The set you are considering is now known as the set of $k$-points of the variety.

For any commutative ring $k$, the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ can be seen as a functor that sends any $k$-algebra $R$ to the set of rank 1 locally free $R[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)$ submodules of $k^2 \otimes_k R[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)$ that are direct summands.  This follows from the Hom-functor description of tangent bundles
$$T_{X/k}(R) = \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(\operatorname{Spec} k[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2), X)(\operatorname{Spec} R) = X(\operatorname{Spec} R[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)),$$
together with a standard functorial description of $\mathbb{P}^1$.  In contrast to the wording in your question, the description of $\mathbb{P}^1$ in terms of submodules does not mention isomorphism classes, and does have a "direct summand" requirement (see for example [this Math.SE page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121105/which-functor-does-the-projective-space-represent)).  There is an alternative functorial description in terms of invertible quotient modules (for example in [the stacks project](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01ND)), and that is where you use an equivalence relation.